# Facebook/Google usage requirements in iOS app to get Apple's approval?

Tags: ios, facebook-login, appstore-approval, google-signin, amazon-cognito

I have developed an iOS app that uses Amazon AWS services. To Authenticate users through Amazon Cognito I am using Facebook and Google login as external identity providers. Apple just rejected my application because I'm using Facebook and Google just for login purposes and am not making extensive use of their features.

My employer wants to setup a Facebook/Google+ page for the application where the app will post on behalf of the app users.  Does anyone know if this use-case would be good enough for Apple to approve the app?  I would also want to know what the minimum requirements of using features are that would be acceptable for Apple.  Thanks!

Comment: is there any manual process to signup? and in the approve process you need to give login details to apple review team as well. if you use facebook login they will have to use their own account. im just thinking that might be the problem

Comment: It's possible that I manage my own authentication, but that requires implementing and maintaining a backend.  We want to use Facebook and Google for the app page, but we don't know if this is enough for the approval.